# Footer is on top. Any solutions without adding a wrapper?

Tags: html, css, sass, layout, semantics

How to make a footer always pressed to bottom?

Whenever I make a new page and there's still no content, considering that my header is fixed, my footer always jumps to top. I want to get rid of this behavior. Maybe there's a solution without adding a wrapper for ,  and  and something that isn't considered a bad practice. If there's no such solution, please, at least give a solution with a wrapper/flexbox.

here red is the footer that's hiding under a fixed header: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtVKL.png

Comment: Try CSS declaration `body {min-height: 100%)` or `body {min-height: 100vh)`

Comment: min-height on body doesn't make sense, because footer and header is a part of a body and we want to only add min-height on the <main> content.

Comment: We can't debug images. Post your code. We need a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

If you have a little content, try avoid “shrinking” of element.

```
body {
  display: flex;
}

Content {
  flex: 1;
}

footer {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I solved this issue by adding a wrapper class to `<main>` and specified `min-height: 100vh`;